# Delete empty rows of a table

Tags: vba

Hello I want to delete empty rows of a table and i am finding issues.

```
 Dim rng As Range
    rng = Sheets("NewForecast").ListObjects("Table").Range.Select
    If rng.Rows = 0 Then
    rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

I don't know how to write it, I tried several ways, looked for here, but could not find an specific solution. I want delete if the Row is completely empty. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: check my code in my answer below and let me know if it suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work on that! Thanks for all who actually opened my mind. Look below, it is simple and doing what I want, macro goes faster too.

```
Range("Table[#Headers]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
    Range("Table").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("Table[#Headers]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: I added some recommended code to get rid of all those "select" that the macro recorder likes to put in there.  Not sure it will work on the first try, but hopefully food for thought.  May need some debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME HERE")
Dim lRow as long
Dim rng as range

lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).row

'Assuming your table starts in column A, put in start/end row numbers
For each rng in ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    If ws.Range("A" & rng.row) = vbNullString then
         ws.Rows(rng.row).Delete
    End if
Next rng
```

Comment: Does not work..The first line and thirds comes errors.

Comment: Try my updated Version. I wrote the this on the fly.

Comment: Nope.. this line For each rng in ws.Cells(Cells(start row, 1),Cells(end row, 1)) does not work

Answer (score 0):

When trying to delete rows in a sheet, always use a backward `For` loop (`For i = 100 to 1 Step -1` for instance).

When checking if a certain `Range` or `Row` is completely empty, the `WorksheetFunction.CountA` comes in quite handy.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

Dim Rng         As Range
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim lRow        As Long

With Sheets("NewForecast")
    Set Rng = .ListObjects("Table").Range

    ' find last row in "Table"
    LastRow = .ListObjects("Table").Range.Rows.Count

    ' loop through all "Table" rows, loop backwards when deleting
    For lRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        ' use CountA to check if entire row is empty
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(lRow)) = 0 Then
            .Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @LeandroMoreira do you have  `Table` object in "NewForecast" sheet ? and that table's name is "Table" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without looping.

1. Filter the table so the values showing are the ones you want to delete
2. Find the first "deletable" row (where cell.value = "") in the last column of the sheet (will most typically be blank, most people don't use the last column),
3. Then find the last "deletable" row (where cell.value = "").

Then use this:

```
Rows(firstRow & ":" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
```

This can be expensive (take a long time) if your field of values is very large but works on sheets as well as tables and is faster (better) than looping.

Comment: I like your idea, Think this could work, although it says "Error 13", Type mismatch

Comment: Yeah, I just kind of threw some steps out there.